# Delayed text (Need it more efficiently delayed) C++

Tags: function, visual-c++, text, delay

Hey guys I have another question, so I am working on a RPG and I am trying to use the Pokemon game type text were one letter pops up at a time. Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

using namespace std;

string name;

VOID WINAPI Sleep(
    _In_ DWORD dwMilliseconds
);

void pushX(int num) {
    for (int i = 0;i<num;i++)
        cout << " ";
}

void main() {

    system("cls");
    cout << "H";
    Sleep(50);
    cout << "e";
    Sleep(50);
    cout << "l";
    Sleep(50);
    cout << "l";
    Sleep(50);
    cout << "o";
    Sleep(50);
    cout << ",";
    Sleep(50);
    cout << " ";
    Sleep(50);
    cout << "W";
    Sleep(50);
    cout << "e";
    Sleep(50);
    cout << "l";
    Sleep(50);
    cout << "c";
    Sleep(50);
    cout << "o";
    Sleep(50);
    cout << "m";
    Sleep(50);
    cout << "e";
    Sleep(50);
    cout << " ";
    Sleep(50);
    cout << "T";
    Sleep(50);
    cout << "o";
    Sleep(50);
    cout << " ";
    Sleep(50);
    cout << "T";
    Sleep(50);
    cout << "h";
    Sleep(50);
    cout << "e";
    Sleep(50);
    cout << " ";
    Sleep(50);
    cout << "G";
    Sleep(50);
    cout << "a";
    Sleep(50);
    cout << "m";
    Sleep(50);
    cout << "e";
    Sleep(50);
    cout << "!\n";
    system("Pause");
    system("cls");
    Sleep(50);
    cout << "P";
    Sleep(50);
    cout << "l";
    Sleep(50);
    cout << "e";
    Sleep(50);
    cout << "a";
    Sleep(50);
    cout << "s";
    Sleep(50);
    cout << "e";
    Sleep(50);
    cout << " ";
    Sleep(50);
    cout << "T";
    Sleep(50);
    cout << "e";
    Sleep(50);
    cout << "l";
    Sleep(50);
    cout << "l";
    Sleep(50);
    cout << " ";
    Sleep(50);
    cout << "M";
    Sleep(50);
    cout << "e";
    Sleep(50);
    cout << " ";
    Sleep(50);
    cout << "Y";
    Sleep(50);
    cout << "o";
    Sleep(50);
    cout << "u";
    Sleep(50);
    cout << "r";
    Sleep(50);
    cout << " ";
    Sleep(50);
    cout << "N";
    Sleep(50);
    cout << "a";
    Sleep(50);
    cout << "m";
    Sleep(50);
    cout << "e";
    Sleep(50);
    cout << "!\n>> ";
    cin >> name;
    system("cls");
    Sleep(50);
    cout << "H";
    Sleep(50);
    cout << "e";
    Sleep(50);
    cout << "l";
    Sleep(50);
    cout << "l";
    Sleep(50);
    cout << "o";
    Sleep(50);
    cout << ",";
    Sleep(50);
    cout << " ";
    Sleep(50);
    cout << name;
    Sleep(50);
    cout << "!\n";
    system("pause");
    return;    

}
```

And this is obviously inefficient. It does the job but way too many lines of code. I also don't want just one line of code that runs on forever. I am looking for maybe a function that finds whenever I put a cout and makes every letter appear at a deley of .050 seconds or Sleep(50); thanks for the help *U*

Comment: Typically games render in a continuous [game loop](http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/game-loop.html) where you'd have each character of text scheduled to show up over multiple frames to give the appearance of 'delayed text'.

Comment: Use a for loop to iterate over a character array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void pokeprint(char* s){
      int N = strlen(s);
      system("cls");
      for(int i=0; i<N;i++)
      {
       Sleep(50);
       cout << s[i];
      }
      cout << "\n";
      system("Pause");
      system("cls");
}
```

Comment: So, I am not that good at functions so how would I call this?

Comment: Ok, I see how it works, It works great, you just put pokeprint("Hello, Welcome To The Game!"); Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Could you tell me how to use Strings along with it, for my name string. When I use cout << name; it skips that then goes to the system("pause"); then it goes back to the cout << name;