# Delayed text in python

Tags: python, text, delay

Similar to my last question: [Delayed text (Need it more efficiently delayed) C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42016655/delayed-text-need-it-more-efficiently-delayed-c). I need to make more efficiently delayed text in python. I tried to alter the other function to make it work but I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: Sounds simple. Loop over every character in the text. In the loop body use `print` and `sleep`. Where's your problem?

Comment: I don't know how to do that, could you send a code example. I just started python yesterday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def delay_print(text, delay):
    for i in text:
        time.sleep(delay)
        print(i, end='')
        sys.stdout.flush()
    print()
```

This is just loops through the given `text` and uses `end=''` to not print a new line until the loop finishes

Comment: Why the name `sPrint` for the function? Why not stick to the [Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) and call the function `delayed_print` or something like that?

Comment: I actually didn't know there was a naming convention, I usually just name things like that. Thanks for showing me that though

Comment: how do I call the function, I figured out with the other one it is poketext("Text Here") but I can't seem to figure it out with this one

Comment: Seriously?? You call it with your string and your delay, delay_print("here is a string but you can use a variable too", 0.05)

Comment: 0.05 is the time in seconds between each character print

Comment: I tried this and it waited about 5 seconds before it said anything, and when it said it, it wasn't delayed text.

Comment: Try flushing stdout after every print, import sys, sys.stdout.flush()

Answer (score 0):

```
import time

msg = "helloworld"
for char in msg:
    print char
    time.sleep(1) #seconds
```

Did you try something like this?